# Is there a better way to initialize EventHandlers in C#

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, nullreferenceexception

Let's say that I am writing a class library of some sort. I have a class:

```
public class PopupControl : UserControl {
    // Some code
    public event EventHandler PopupFinished;
}
```

If I want to handle this event in another class, I just use the `+=` operator and nothing special happens. However, when the event is *not* handled anywhere, `PopupFinished` is `null`. And when I call `PopupFinished (this, EventArgs.Empty)`, I get a `NullReferenceException`. So I need to do this:

```
public PopupControl () {
    PopupFinished += popupFinished;
    //Some more code
}

private void popupFinished (object sender, EventArgs e) {}
```

This doesn't sound like a good programming practice though. (or is it?)

Then I thought of another way:

```
try {
    PopupFinished (this, EventArgs.Empty);
} catch (NullReferenceException) {}
```

But that doesn't sound right either.

Please tell me which of the above is better and whether there is another way to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a test to check `PopupFinished` is not null before calling it.

```
if(PopupFinished != null)
    PopupFinished();
```

Comment: The new C# allows the safe navigation operator (PopupFinished?.Invoke...) too.

Comment: Is this not the same as the `try...catch` method ?

Comment: In a try...catch, the exception occurs, then it is handled. This does not allow the exception to occur. This is better because it takes a significant amount of time for the exception to occur and be handled compared to running through an if statement

Comment: OK, I see. Answer Accepted!